# What is wrong with this framework if I get this error while uploading a build to the iTunes Store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

"Code signing for MyFramework.framework failed"

[image]

Side note: I added the framework to embedded binaries. If I use "linked frameworks" then there is a different error.

Comment: Have you viewed distribution logs for more information? :-)

Comment: Yea, I don't know how to read them though :(

Comment: Start with looking (searching?) for signs of something going wrong: errors, failures, etc. — that may give you some clue. If you find a suspicious area but can't understand it, you can at least copy-paste it here so that others can help.